# use case when to show column conditional value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, case

I would like to add a column and show customer rewards status based on their points.
However, MySQL states there is an error in the syntax which I cannot figure out why.
My code is as below, I got the error msg that SELECT is not valid at this position.

```
SELECT customer_id, first_name,
CASE points
    WHEN > 3000 THEN 'Gold'
    WHEN BETWEEN 2000 to 3000 THEN 'Silver'
    ELSE 'Bronze'
END AS rewards_status
FROM customers
```

Answer (score 1):

The short syntax for `case`, which you are using here (like: `case <expr> when <val> then ... end`) only supports equality condition; this does not fit your use case, which requires inequality conditions. You need to use the long `case` syntax (like: `case when <condition> then ... end`).

Also, there is no need for `between` in the second condition. Branches of a `case` expression are evaluated sequentially, and the process stops as soon as a condition is fullfilled, so you can do:

```
select
    customer_id,
    first_name
    case
        when points > 3000 then 'Gold'
        when points > 2000 then 'Silver'
        else 'Bronze'
   end as reward_status
from customers
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the alternative syntax for `CASE` expressions here:

```
SELECT
    customer_id,
    first_name,
    CASE WHEN points > 3000 THEN 'Gold'
         WHEN points BETWEEN 2000 to 3000 THEN 'Silver'
         ELSE 'Bronze' END AS rewards_status
FROM customers;
```